# using vertical align and height together

Tags: html, css

if i use `vertical-align: middle;` itself without giving `height`, it is working. once i give height, vertical-align is not working.

CSS

```
.inlineblock{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:  10px;
    background: #4f81bd;
    color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>information here</p>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>more information here</p>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>another more information here</p>
</div>
```

How can use use vertical-align: middle together with height?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5mmvsey4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `display: table-cell`

```css
.inlineblock{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:  10px;
    background: #4f81bd;
    color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>information here</p>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>more information here</p>
</div>
<div class="inlineblock">
<p>another more information here</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :**

```css
section{
 display:table;
 border-collapse:separate;
 border-spacing:5px;
 }
.row {
 display:table-row;
}
.inlineblock {
 display:table-cell;
 width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:  10px;
    background: #4f81bd;
    color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="inlineblock">
       <p>information here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inlineblock">
    <p>more information here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inlineblock">
    <p>another more information here</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```